# OpenGL first person jumping code

Tags: java, opengl

I'm making a game in Java with LWJGL and I just implemented jumping. I don't really think the code is particularly well written or very efficient. Here is the code of my `Camera` class:

```
public void startJump(float height, float land){
    jumpHeight = height;
    jumpLand = land;
    if(!falling && !jumping)
        jumping = true;
}

private void jump(){ // called every frame
    if(jumping){
        if(y >= -jumpHeight){
            y -= jumpSpeed;
        }else{
            jumping = false;
            falling = true;
        }
    }

    if(falling){
        if(y <= -jumpLand){
            y += jumpSpeed;
        }else{
            jumping = false;
            falling = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone knows a cleaner or more efficient method please tell me!

EDIT:

I was thinking of using `jumping` and `!jumping` but this introduces a bug where if the jump key is held down then the player hovers in the air so unless your making a jet-pack use `jumping` and `falling`.

Comment: You got bad performance? the code is good after all. A question: if a player is `jumping` `falling` will never be true? and if a player is `falling` `jumping` will never be true? I Mean: can `jumping` and `falling` be true together?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno My performance is fine, I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way rather than checking the player is jumping every frame. Also, falling and jumping will never be true at the same time so I have changed it to `jumping` and `!jumping`. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your comment, the only change i could say is to change

```
private void jump(){ // called every frame
    if(jumping){
        if(y >= -jumpHeight){
            y -= jumpSpeed;
        }else{
            jumping = false;
            falling = true;
        }
    }

    if(falling){
```

to

```
private void jump(){ // called every frame
    if(jumping){
        if(y >= -jumpHeight){
            y -= jumpSpeed;
        }else{
            jumping = false;
            falling = true;
        }
    }

    else if(falling){
```

To avoid to check falling too if it's jumping. But its a macro optimization (useless too maybe in this case.)
But really, this code is perfect how it is. So go ahead!

Just got this idea in my mind: you could define a "PlayerStatus" enum with: Falling, Jumping but it will affect the logic of your game, change it only if you think you will need more status and maintain two boolean variables (or more if you add more conditions) will be hard. If you need only one turned on and others off.. it's a great way to do it:

```
enum PlayerStatus
{
    FALLING,
    JUMPING
}
```

and use the enum to change the status..

```
PlayerStatus status;
status = PlayerStatus.FALLING;
```